# How may I create custom claims in onCreate?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am working with firebase and firebase cloud functions. 
When a user is created with `auth`, I want to set custom claims based on their email. I am trying to achieve this using `functions.auth.user().onCreate(....)`.

However, when I try to add custom claims, I get the following error in the console: `There is no user record corresponding to the provided identifier`.

I have tried numerous examples of this online, for example the one in [Google's docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims?authuser=0#access_custom_claims_on_the_client). 
I have also tried to manually create the user before adding custom claims, like this:

```js
await auth().createUser({...user});
```

```js
export const signupProcess = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {

    // Check if user meets role criteria.
    const admin = (user.email && admins.has(user.email)? true: false);
    const customClaims = { admin };
    // Set custom user claims on this newly created user.
    return auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, customClaims)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
});
```

I am expecting to gain access to admin with correct emails.
However, I get the described error on user creation.

Comment: What is the value of `auth()` because you should normally call `admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims()`?

Comment: Also, which sign-in provider are you using to create the user?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Auth is imported from "firebase-admin", 'import { auth, initialiseApp, credentials } from "firebase-admin" :-) (sorry about formatting, only have access to ios app)

Comment: Did you use `firebase-functions` latest version? At first, would you try to debug using `console.log('user.uid')`?

Comment: @zkohi I was using 2.3.0. I have now upgraded to 2.3.1.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Google is the provider :-)

Comment: @zkohi I logged out the uid. It is the same as the one registered in "authentication".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried simple code.

I could set custom user claims.

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp();

export const setCustomUserClaimsAdmin = functions.auth.user().onCreate(
  async (user: functions.auth.UserRecord): Promise<any> => {
    try {
      return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
        ...user.customClaims,
        ...{ admin: true }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
);
```

See https://github.com/zkohi/firebase-web-samples/tree/microsoft-oauth/functions .

Could you try simple code or insert debug code more?

Comment: Thank you for this! The function does not log any error. However, I am still unable to access stuff reserved for admin. However, that may be an issue with my firestore.rules. Thus, not part of this question.

I will investigate further this eventing.

Comment: Thanks again! Turned out, what was left was to manually refresh the token on the client side :-)

Comment: Am I wrong or in this example every user created will be an admin?

Comment: @FrancescoClementi Yes, you are right. This is `setCustomUserClaims()` example. If you want to specified user to set admin, you should set any condition(ex. mail address) before call `setCustomUserClaims()`.